# What is the pink featus looking thing on my dwarfy's belly and the white spots on his legs?

Tags: frogs

[image: Dwarfy's belly and white spots on legs]

What is the featus looking thing on my dwarfys belly? What are the qhite spots on its legs?

Comment: you need to give a lot more information,like the water parameters,temperature,how long have you had the frog,any other animals in your tank,do your frog get natural sunlight,what type of light do you use for your tank and is it full spectrum.